# What's does 白紙 (Hakushi) really stand for?

Tags: colors

Some websites say it stands for Enlightenment, Paper White, but others say it means Weak Willed. I'm confused on which one is right?

Comment: This is not really a difficult word. Which website(s) did you see?

Comment: Jlearn(dot)net says it means weak willed and other sites say it's White (color) or Enlightenment, I just don't know which one to believe.

Comment: All of those translations are plain wrong. I believe you're seeing [a wrong word](https://jlearn.net/Dictionary/Browse/1690500-hakushi-はくし-薄志) which happens to have the same reading. Make sure you're inputting correct kanji.

Answer (score 4):

白紙 means:

1. blank paper; blank/unfilled form; blank sheet
2. scratch (as in "from scratch"); no progress; blank slate; *tabula rasa*
3. (literally) paper that is white

See the definition on [jlearn.net](https://jlearn.net/Dictionary/Browse/1475200-hakushi-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97-%E7%99%BD%E7%B4%99) and [jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%99%BD%E7%B4%99). 白紙 never means *englightment* nor *weak will*. I believe you have made some weird mistake when you looked it up.

Note that *white paper* in [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_paper) is 白書 or ホワイトペーパー.